# I don't understand the logical leap made in the analogy of $e$

Tags: limits, exponential-function, infinity

$e$ is often explained in terms of compound interest. If I found a bank that gave me 100% annual compound interest, then if I put in £1.00, at the end of the year, I would have £2.00. If I were more savvy, and instead asked for 50% interest paid biannually, then I would end up with more – £2.25 to be exact. (This is because 50% of £1.50 > 50% of £1 – simple interest, rather than compound interest, would still only give me £2.00.) $e$ appears to be the logical extreme of this idea: of taking $\frac{100%}{n}$% interest $n$ times per year. I understand it as the limit of $(1+1/n)$ as $n$ tends to infinity. When the analogy starts to break down for me is when it is therefore concluded that you can take the interest infinitely/continually often. Obviously, this is conceptually harder already, because of the introduction of infinity. However, it is also seems to beg the question "what is the interest rate?". If it is 0%, then the £1.00 will never increase, but any more than 0%, and then the individual interest rates would no longer add up to 100%. Is it some kind of infinitesimal?

To illustrate my wariness, I have this example from the wikipedia article on limits (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(mathematics)): $$f(x)=\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$$
As $x$ gets arbitrarily close to 1, $f(x)$ approaches 2, no matter which side you approach 1 from. However, $f(1)$ is undefined as involves division by zero. Similarly, as $n$ tends to infinity in the $e$ analogy, the growth rate becomes arbitrarily close to $e$. But I don't see how this means that when $n=\infty$, the growth rate is necessarily $e$. After all, if you plug $n=\infty$ into the normal formula $(1+1/n)^n$, it seems that it breaks down (forgive me if you cannot use infinity in this way).

Comment: In the computation where you get 100% interest at the end of the year, the interest rate is 100% per year.  In the computation where you get 50% twice per year, the interest rate is 100% per year.  In the limit, the interest rate is 100% per year.  Only the compounding period is changing.  Alternatively, you could consider the effective interest rate (which will be something like 172% per year), or the instantaneous interest rate, which will be related to the derivative of the amount of money you have in savings.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Sorry, I was unfamiliar with all the different types of interest rate. What I was referring to when I said "50% paid biannually" was that twice per year your money was multiplied by 1.5, but I understand if I wasn't clear enough about this in my question. The primary question I was asking was "what are you multiplying by each time?".

Comment: When you say "plug $n=\infty$ into the normal formula" this doesn't make any sense. What does make sense is the limit as $n$ tends to $\infty$ i.e. an arbitrarily large number. This value is called $e$.

Comment: The upper bound for earnings, due to compounding, for any interest rate is $e-1\approx 1.71828...$. It is a theoretical maximum that one can earn at any given interest rate (APR). It is hardly different from daily compounding. A daily compounding rate would give $\approx 1.71456..$, a difference of about $0.37\%$ APY

Comment: @PeterForeman This is what I intuitively thought. However, why then is there all this talk about charging interest infinitely often?  It seems like $n=\infty$, rather than n is tending to infinity (which makes sense to me).

Comment: @Joe If you are paid 100% once per year, then the "average rate of change" over a that year is 100%.  If you are paid 50% twice per year, then the "average rate of change" over each 6 month period is 50%.  However, when you take the limit, the "average rate of change" no longer makes sense.  Instead, you need to consider an "instantaneous rate of change", which is the derivative.  You aren't being paid a finite amount of interest infinitely often once you take a limit.

Comment: @Joe One cannot charge interest infinitely often. We define limits to rigourously define notions such as charging interest at a rate "tending to infinity". But here the phrase "tending to infinity" encapsulates the definition of a limit.

Comment: Rather than speaking of compounding "infinitely often", a more sensible phrase (one that your Question touches upon briefly) is "continuous compounding".  One then has a function for the principal plus interest that has the form $e^{rt}$ where $t$ is time and $r$ the rate of interest compatible with units of time involved.

Comment: @PeterForeman Thank you. As a side note: when people the infinite series 1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + ... equals 2, this is defined to mean the limit of the series. However, is this the same as adding "all" the terms up (is that even possible?). I've felt really confused about this. Because from what I've worked out, you can sum infinitely many terms, whereas you can't charge interest infinitely often. 1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + ... really does equal 2 (but not at any finite point), whereas charging interest infinitely often is non-sensical.

Comment: @Joe Typically the notation $1+1/2+1/4+\dots$ means $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n(1/2^k)$. Here the $\infty$ just means that $n$ is made arbitrarily large in order to approach the "infinite sum" of the series. When you say "adding all of the terms up" the standard interpretation of this is to start adding the terms from the beginning and studying the partial sums. If they converge to a finite value we could say that the sum of "all" the terms is this value. But you would never consider every term simultaneously.

Comment: You could imagine that somebody was earning compound interest with some large value of $n$. And some banker may have said, "Heck, let's just say the amount of money our client has at time $t$ is $Pe^{rt}$. The result is almost the same anyway." When presenting this idea to potential clients the bankers could describe it in an impressive sounding way by saying the interest is being "compounded continuously".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

e is defined (or one of its definitions) to be $$\lim _{n \to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{n})^n$$, and not to be when you plug in n as infinity. Most of our math is defined as a limit, and doesn’t make any sense when you simply plug in infinity. For example, take the simple function $\frac{1}{x}$. You can say the limit as x goes to infinity is zero, but you cannot say that $\frac{1}{\infty}$ is zero, because our basic functions are only defined for finite numbers. When we say interest taken continually we mean interest taken as defined by a limit to infinity.

Comment: I think things a bit clearer. Thanks for this answer. Is there any way you can clarify what you meant by your last sentence? So, we cannot taken interest literally 'continually', but as n gets larger and larger, the interval at which you compound the interest gets smaller and smaller (hence the term continually).

Comment: Yes, exactly. We can compound arbitrarily small, but not zero, as like you have figured out, doesn't exactly make any sense. When people say "infinitely small" they do mean as the limit goes towards infinity, but that is too much of a bother to write out.